# 64-bit Inno Setup installer is writing files to "C:\Program Files (x86)" instead of "C:\Program Files"

Tags: inno-setup

I'm converting an existing Inno Setup script to install a 64-bit Windows application. I've set the x64 Inno Setup properties in my script, but the installer is still copying files to the x86 folder when I run it.

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
```

Here's a snippet of my installer's log file:

```
Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.6.1 (u)
Windows version: 10.0.22621  (NT platform: Yes)
64-bit Windows: Yes
Processor architecture: x64
User privileges: Administrative
64-bit install mode: Yes
  ...
Non-default bitness: 32-bit
```

This is how I specify a file to be copied:

```
Source: "bin\{#TesterWpfExe}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

What's odd is that I've converted another Inno Setup script to 64-bit and it is working just fine. It seems there must be something different about this problematic script, but I have not figured out what the problem could be.

Are there other factors that could be causing the installer to revert to 32-bit mode?

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the application (same [`AppId`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid)) already installed on the machine.

Reinstalling it will (by default – [`UsePreviousAppDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_usepreviousappdir)) use the previous installation folder, no matter that you have possibly changed the `DefaultDirName` (from `{pf}` to `{autopf}`?).

Uninstall the application and try a fresh installation.